# New blog post! "Writing Good ‘Meaning’ Questions"

Tags: discussion, blog

Our very own [Mahnax](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11550/mahnax) has christened the relaunch of the blog with a great post on how to ask meaning questions — a topic that sorely needed expounding on.

> On any Stack Exchange site, a question must be tagged. Here at EL&U, our most popular tag is the meaning tag, with over 2700 questions filed as such. Unfortunately, this tag is often misused, and many questions bearing this tag are closed, with some being subsequently deleted. Luckily, the EL&U blog is here to save the day...

[**Read more**](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/)

Comment: Excellent! But where is the link to the blog on the regular ELU main site?

Comment: @Mitch - good question. There is a link at the very bottom of the page, on the main site. It's just above the list of other SE sites, amongst "about", "faq", etc. I hope the other link appears next to the chat link at the top...

Comment: New blog posts are announced in the COMMUNITY BULLETIN box in the right side column. In fact announcing them here is probably unnecessary: meta posts are also announced there, and that creates duplication and pushes other meta / blog posts out of the box.